# Angular 5+ TS2339: Property does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have a sample user register/login Node.js/Angular app that worked completely fine on Angular 4, but after I updated to 5.1.0 it gives me errors.

Express.js function to authenticate user:

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user) {
      return res.json({ success: false, msg:'User not found' });
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 604800
        });

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: 'JWT ' + token,
          user: {
            id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({ success: false, msg:'Wrong password' });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Angular authenticate service function:

```
authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3002/users/authenticate',
      user, { headers: headers });
  }
```

Login component function:

```
onLoginSubmit() {
    const user =  {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success) {
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.flashMessagesService.show('You are now logged in',
          { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.flashMessagesService.show(data.msg,
          { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 5000 });
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });
  }
```

Error output:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/login/login.component.ts(31,15): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/components/login/login.component.ts(32,45): error TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/components/login/login.component.ts(32,57): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/components/login/login.component.ts(36,45): error TS2339: Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/components/profile/profile.component.ts(20,27): error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/components/register/register.component.ts(51,15): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Comment: Your have to tell your http post method the return type or it will assume `Object`, causing your type errors. So it should be something like `this.http.post<User>(...)`